# Are there any advantages of Cloud SQL Proxy over a DBaaS?

Tags: database, google, heroku

I'm currently migrating an app from Heroku to Google Cloud Platform (GKE and Cloud SQL). With Heroku, I've become used to the incredibly simple practice of defining a `DATABASE_URL` and letting their Heroku Postgres DBaaS do all of the work of connecting my backend to the database:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@host:port/database
```

With Python, I could use [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) and it couldn't be easier.

Now, I'm working on connecting each of my Docker containers to my Cloud SQL instance through the [Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy), and it's a pain.

My question is: Why did Google go with this approach rather than a DBaaS approach? Are there any advantages? Or is it just that building a DBaaS like Heroku Postgres would take a lot of resources?

Comment: There is actually a lot of discussion about what the Google Cloud Proxy provides / why you’d use it in the link you included in the question.

Comment: Ah cool, I'll read it more closely then